# Join 4 tables and sum quantity for 2 tables using id from one table

Tags: sql-server, left-join

My tables:

[image]

Order is:

```
PurchaseOrderHead
PurchaseOrder
ReceivingNoteHead
ReceivingNote
```

I want the output like this

```
MaterialID, PO.Quantity, RN.Quantity so far
```

There can be multiple receiving notes for a given `purchaseorderhead_id` as every `ReceivingNoteHead` will have a `PurchaseOrderHeadID`.

My attempt:

```
select 
    PurchaseOrder.MaterialID,
    sum(distinct PurchaseOrder.Quantity) as "Sum_Quantity",
    sum(ReceivingNote.Quantity) as "ReceivingNote_Quantity",
    PurchaseOrderHead.id
from 
    (((dbo.PurchaseOrder
inner join 
    dbo.PurchaseOrderHead on (PurchaseOrderHead.id = PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderHeadID))
left outer join 
    dbo.ReceivingNoteHead ReceivingNoteHead (ReceivingNoteHead.PurchaseOrderHeadID = PurchaseOrderHead.id))
left outer join 
    dbo.ReceivingNote on (ReceivingNote.ReceivingNoteHeadID = ReceivingNoteHead.id))
group by
    PurchaseOrder.MaterialID,
    PurchaseOrderHead.id
having 
    (PurchaseOrderHead.id = 1004)
```

But `ReceivingNote Quantities` are repeated when there's no `ReceivingNote` `MaterialID` that matches `PurchaseOrder's MaterialID`.

This also does not work when theres multiple same `MaterialID` in either `PurchaseOrder` or `ReceivingNote`

I would like to learn whether I need to break the ReceivingNote table into 2 tables because of `PurchaseOrderHeadID`? And I want to get rid of the `sum distinct` because it's not the way I want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe by first aggregating the material purchases in a sub-query.
Then left join that to the materials on the receiving end.

Untested notepad scribble:

```
SELECT 
 poMat.MaterialID,
 poMat.TotQuantity AS [PurchaseOrder_Quantity],
 SUM(rn.Quantity) AS [ReceivingNote_Quantity],
 poMat.PurchaseOrderHeadID
FROM
(
   SELECT 
    po.PurchaseOrderHeadID, 
    po.MaterialID,
    SUM(po.Quantity) AS TotQuantity
   FROM dbo.PurchaseOrder po
   -- Uncomment to filter on the PurchaseOrderHeadID
   -- WHERE po.PurchaseOrderHeadID = 1004
   GROUP BY 
   po.PurchaseOrderHeadID, 
   po.MaterialID
) poMat
LEFT JOIN dbo.ReceivingNoteHead rnH 
  ON rnH.PurchaseOrderHeadID = poMat.PurchaseOrderHeadID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ReceivingNote rn
  ON rn.ReceivingNoteHeadID = rnH.id
 AND rn.MaterialID = poMat.MaterialID
GROUP BY 
 poMat.PurchaseOrderHeadID, 
 poMat.MaterialID,
 poMat.TotQuantity
ORDER BY 
 poMat.PurchaseOrderHeadID, 
 poMat.MaterialID;
```

This however, won't show received materials that don't have a matching purchased material.

Comment: this seem to be ok. I am also using `having ReceivingNote sum(Quantity) < PurchaseOrder sum(Quantity) * 0.9`. but when a value is null. it does not show that row. How do I handle null values here?

Comment: Maybe `HAVING ISNULL(SUM(rn.Quantity),0) < poMat.TotQuantity * 0.9` in the outer-query?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplicate because the table ReceivingNoteHead  does not have the PurchaseOrder.ID in it. Add the column *PurchaseOrderID* in ReceivingNoteHead and you should be good to go

```
select 
    PurchaseOrder.MaterialID,
    sum(PurchaseOrder.Quantity) as "Sum_Quantity",
    sum(ReceivingNote.Quantity) as "ReceivingNote_Quantity",
    PurchaseOrderHead.id
from 
   dbo.PurchaseOrder
inner join 
    dbo.PurchaseOrderHead on PurchaseOrderHead.id = PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderHeadID
left outer join 
    dbo.ReceivingNoteHead ReceivingNoteHead ReceivingNoteHead.PurchaseOrderHeadID = PurchaseOrderHead.id *and ReceivingNoteHead.PurchaseOrderID=PurchaseOrder.ID*
left outer join 
    dbo.ReceivingNote on ReceivingNote.ReceivingNoteHeadID = ReceivingNoteHead.id
group by
    PurchaseOrder.MaterialID,
    PurchaseOrderHead.id
having 
    PurchaseOrderHead.id = 1004
```

Comment: Add PurchaseOrder id to ReceivingNoteHead? There is already a PurchaseOrderHeadID in ReceivingNoteHead and PurchaseOrderID(from PurchaseOrder, which is a detail table) is a collection of IDs for Material List, which is why single ReceivingNoteHead cannot have multiple PurchaseOrder IDs(detail table)

Comment: `and ReceivingNoteHead.PurchaseOrderID = PurchaseOrder.ID` if here you mean `and ReceivingNoteHead.PurchaseOrderHeadID = PurchaseOrderHead.ID` ?

Comment: I think I may have finally fixed it.
I added `PurchaseOrder` id to `ReceivingNote` table.
So every `MaterialID`, `Quantity` in `ReceivingNote` now has a `PurchaseOrder ` id. I am going to test it with multiple rows data to make sure that it's correct.

Comment: adding  PurchaseOrderid to ReceivingNote table works as well if that is how you designed it. Adding it to ReceivingNoteHead would help you in increasing the complexity of RecievingNote and subsequent tables in the future without having to add PurchasingOrder ID to each and every table

Comment: `and ReceivingNoteHead.PurchaseOrderID = PurchaseOrder.ID` by this I mean, after adding PurchaseOrderID  to ReceivingNoteHead, this condition would help you eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Adding PurchaseOrder id to ReceivingNoteHead requires that ReceivingNoteHead have multiple rows because PurchaseOrder can have multiple ids because of it being the collection of material. I can't wrap my head around it. Could you explain it?

Comment: Is PurchaseOrder connected to each RecievingNoteHead or is the RecievingNoteHead independent of a Purchase Order? 
If 1 RecievingNoteHead correlates to 1 PurchaseOrder the add PurchaseOrder.id to RecievingNoteHead. 
If 1 RecievingNoteHead correlates to multiple PurchaseOrders then add the RecievingNoteHead.ID to the PurchaseOrder table.
If it is a many to many relations create a third table which will store, PurchaseOrder.ID and RecievingNoteHead.ID. It depends on how data is being stored in the tables.

Comment: A PurchaseOrderHead can contain multiple PurchaseOrder Material and Quantities.
A ReceivingNoteHead may contain a PurchaseOrderHeadID multiple times  Because a receiving could be partial. So to ensure that the remaining Material and Quantities are tallied with the PurchaseOrder everytime a new ReceivingNoteHead is opened with the same PurchaseOrderHeadID. The PurchaseOrderHeadID is saved into ReceivingNoteHead, and for now PurchaseOrder id for a given Material is also saved in the ReceivingNote material entry.

Comment: a PO can have multiple receiving. But a single receiving will never have multiple purchase orders. It will always be against a given purchase order.

Comment: by PO do you mean PurchaseOrder or PurchaseOrderHead?

Comment: sorry, PurchaseOrderHead. In our current business process, once a PO Head created, is sent to the vendor. They send us back a goods with a receiving note for Purchase Order Head. This receiving note maybe a partial delivery. Which is why the whole need for multiple ReceivingNoteHeads for a given PurchaseOrderHead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203311/discussion-between-ankyskywalker-and-user2185284).